# Probably incorrect release file causing apt-get update to fail

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I’m installing a VM of Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC.

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get a response:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried to reinstall the VM and it didn't fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check my answer on: http://askubuntu.com/a/633863/418100
Select appropriate server from list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions (the last one should resolve the problem in case other ones fail) for them who still face this problem:

**1. Remove cached files:**

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

and if required, the files in `partials` too:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partials/* -vf
```

and then try `sudo apt-get update`

**2. Modify sources.list:**

You might edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` making necessary changes to the list of repository names. If sources.list gets corrupted somehow, then you could delete it and could generate a fresh one. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list) might be of great help in this regard.

**3. Choose a different server:**

Go to `Software & Updates` -> `Ubuntu Software`. From `Download from`, select `other...` and select a preferable server which is different from the previous one. You can click `Select Best Server` and let the system choose the best server for you. You will be prompted to refresh after changing the server. Finally, `sudo apt-get update` should work fine thereafter.

**Note:** I had the same problem which was resolved by the 3rd solution. I was also unable to download some application from `Terminal` and `Ubuntu Software Center` as well.

Comment: Well, the 3rd solution is already mentioned by Abhishek under the comment section of the question.

Comment: I did the 1st and the 3rd, and it worked for me. Thanks!
Any idea why this error comes though?

Comment: kudos! third one worked for me, though I was facing this issue in backbox. however, it helped. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open your Terminal and execute the below command line (to reset the repositories):

```
sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now it should be fixed.

Comment: still not working: `Fetched 12.0 kB in 1s (9,803 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
`